# Multiple Results For A Variable - SQL

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Firstly I apologise, I am new to SQL.

I'm trying to figure out how I can input multiple values for a defined variable.

Currently I am using the following;

```
UNDEFINE MPAN_CORE
SELECT customer.MPAN.j0003 AS MPAN, customer.AGENT.j0183 AS DA, customer.AGENT.j0205 AS DC, customer.agent.j0178 AS MOP
FROM customer.mpan
    INNER JOIN customer.agent
        ON customer.mpan.uniq_id = customer.agent.mpan_lnk
WHERE customer.mpan.j0003 = '&&MPAN_CORE'
```

Basically I want to be able to input multiple values for customer MPAN, and have multiple results. Currently I am having to input one MPAN at a time.

Not sure if this is even possible, maybe its as simple as using a character to divide my input values?

Any help is much appreciated

Thanks

Comment: I would never give SQL Developer or SQL*Plus as an interactive UI to the end user. What are you trying to achieve? From where would the values come from? Application? Also **equality operator** `=` will not work for a list of values, you need to use **IN** operator.

Comment: I have a list of values (MPANs) and I want the linked values (DA, DC, MOP) to be returned from the agent table. but currently I am having to do this one at a time.

Comment: Then you need to use **IN** list. Can you hardcode those values in the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> WHERE customer.mpan.j0003 = '&&MPAN_CORE'

you cannot have multiple values with equality operator `=`. For multiple values, you need to use **IN list**.

For example,

```
SQL> SELECT empno, deptno FROM emp WHERE ename IN ('SMITH','KING','SCOTT');

     EMPNO     DEPTNO
---------- ----------
      7369         20
      7788         20
      7839         10

SQL>
```

Or, using **substitution variable**:

```
SQL> SELECT empno, deptno FROM emp WHERE ename IN (&a);
Enter value for a: 'SMITH','KING','SCOTT'
old   1: SELECT empno, deptno FROM emp WHERE ename IN (&a)
new   1: SELECT empno, deptno FROM emp WHERE ename IN ('SMITH','KING','SCOTT')

     EMPNO     DEPTNO
---------- ----------
      7369         20
      7788         20
      7839         10

SQL>
```